# After installing jekyll, getting -bash: jekyll command not found

Tags: ruby, jekyll

hey there jekyll users... I am new to using ruby/rvm and have followed the instructions to install it on my mac locally, and then installed the jekyll gem, but when i try to run jekyll commands I get

```
bash: jekyll: command not found
```

Any advice?

I know that when I installed rvm, (or maybe it was during the homebrew install), I received a notice that I have both `.profile` and `.bash_profile` and it asked me to add `source ~/.profile` to `.bash_profile` could that be the problem?

I've also tried installing using this command `gem install --source http://rubygems.org jekyll`
and it says it installs but when I try jekyll in the terminal, I keep getting command not found.

If there is any more information I need to post to help, please let me know.

Comment: What I ended up doing is switching my Ruby version (I was using 2.0) using RVM and then reinstalling. Using 1.9.3 I was able to run Jekyll fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that when I installed rvm, (or maybe it was during the homebrew install), I received a notice that I have both .profile and .bash_profile and it asked me to add source ~/.profile to .bash_profile could that be the problem?

Yes. Do what it said there and you should have access to the `jekyll` command.

```
user$ echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I read most of the solutions around the web and most of them seem to suggest a $PATH change. I don't like to edit my path unless I have to so I just did a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.2.1/bin/jekyll
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer for 2020 (soon 2021).

One of the reasons you can get "command not found" after installing gems is because they were installed in a location that your bash shell does not yet know about. The way the computer looks up commands is by looking at the `PATH`, which is a list of folders where the computer should look for commands, such as `jekyll`.

The location of the gems depends on how you installed Ruby, and since there are [many ways to install Ruby on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/), how to fix the "command not found" error will depend on how you installed Ruby. If you used a Ruby manager, such as RVM, rbenv, or chruby, then you might have missed a step in the installation instructions. They typically take care of the `PATH` for you automatically with a script. If you installed Ruby with Homebrew, then you'll need to add `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin` to your `PATH`, for example:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

(Replace `.bash_profile` with `.zshrc` if you are using `zsh`. If you're not sure which shell you're using, read this: https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/which-shell-am-i-using-how-can-i-switch/)

I strongly believe that there should only be one recommended way to install Ruby, which is with a Ruby manager. I prefer [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) because it's the lightest and easiest to use. I wrote a script that will automatically set up a proper Ruby environment for you with `chruby`, including updating your `PATH` and everything else that is necessary to be able to install gems and use them right away without getting any errors.

You can read more about my script and other ways to fix the "command not found" error in these articles:

https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/troubleshooting-command-not-found-in-the-terminal/
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-jekyll-on-a-mac-the-easy-way/
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/